# Find emails that are present on a spammers table of domains

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with user emails (Accounts) and another with a list of temporary email addresses domains (Spammers).

### Accounts table

```
 id |          email          
----+-------------------------
  1 | test111122@example.com
  2 | test1111223@example.com
  3 | test@sharklasers.com
```

#### Spammers table

```
 id  |                 domain                  
-----+-----------------------------------------
   1 | 0-mail.com
   2 | 0815.ru
   3 | sharklasers.com
```

#### Results after query

```
 id |          email          
----+-------------------------
  3 | test@sharklasers.com
```

How can I obtain all the emails on the Accounts table that are from Spammers?

I know there are many accepted email formats, but currently I'm only interested on the "standard" ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Schmitt has the right idea, although his approach a bit too lax, as it doesn't take into account the position of the `'@'` character in the email. Consider, for example, that `spam.com` is a spam domain. Frank's query will catch any email from that domain, but will although catch any user from the completely legal `notspam.com` domain.

Using something like `regexp_replace` to identify the domain exactly would resolve this:

```
SELECT email
FROM   users u
JOIN   spammers s ON s.domain = REGEXP_REPLACE(u.email, '.*@', '')
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46fc1/3/0)**

Comment: Yes, I was expecting something more on this line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `JOIN` with a `LIKE` search (added @ to avoid false positives, as pointed out by @Mureinik):

```
select email from users u
join spammers s 
  on u.email like '%@' || s.domain;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5cf0d/2/0)

Comment: The idea is right, but it ignores the position of the `@` and thus may catch legal emails too. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40819586/2422776) for a slightly more robust approach, IMHO.

Comment: @Mureinik Hadn't thought of that - I've fixed it, thanks for pointing this out.